# d3 equivalent of jQuery find("*")

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I currently use jQuerys's find('*').method to get all children of a svg element:

```
$(svg).find("*").each(function(){
  //do s.th.
});
```

I want the same with d3 and I tried:

```
d3.select(svg).selectAll().each(function() {
  //do s.th.
});
```

but

```
d3.select(svg).selectAll().size()
```

always returns 1 although the SVG has several child elements.
What am I doing wrong?

If ypu want to see where this issue applies or need an example: [SVG to Image export performance issues (using canvg / XMLSerializer / getComputedStyle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944691/svg-to-image-performance-issues)

Comment: `d3.select(svg).selectAll("*")`

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that `selectAll()` is the same of `selectAll(null)`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d3.select(svg).selectAll("*")
```

did it. thanks to altocumulus
I could swear that I had already tested that... thank you anyway